# Modify the legend of a double doughnut with chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a legend for a doughnut chart created with chart js. The problem is I have two doughnut charts stacked and when creating the legend it defaults to the labels of the first.

[image]

I want the legend to show up with the blue label as CPU and a green label as MEM.
Currently the labels when hovering on either doughnut is free and used which I'd like to keep.

here is the script used to create the chart

```
var responseChartLoad = new Chart(responseChartCanvas, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Used", "Free"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [0, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#42a5f5',
                '#eceff1',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#FFF',
                '#FFF'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2
        }, {
            data: [0, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#4db6ac',
                '#eceff1',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#FFF',
                '#FFF'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        cutoutPercentage: 50,
        animation: {
            animateRotate: true
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        elements: {
            center: {
                text: 'CPU/MEM',
                fontStyle: 'Helvetica', //Default Arial
                sidePadding: 50 //Default 20 (as a percentage)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: are you trying to add another set of legends like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YItYN.png) ?

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the free and used legend and only have CPU and MEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish that you would have to generate custom legend items, which could be done using the [**`generateLabels`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) method of legend­*'s* labels, as such :

```
legend: {
   labels: {
      generateLabels: function() {
         return [{
            text: 'CPU',
            fillStyle: '#42a5f5',
            strokeStyle: '#fff'
         }, {
            text: 'MEM',
            fillStyle: '#4db6ac',
            strokeStyle: '#fff'
         }];
      }
   }
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var responseChartLoad = new Chart('responseChartCanvas', {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {
      labels: ["Used", "Free"],
      datasets: [{
         data: [10, 100],
         backgroundColor: [
            '#42a5f5',
            '#eceff1',
         ],
         borderColor: [
            '#FFF',
            '#FFF'
         ],
         borderWidth: 2
      }, {
         data: [5, 100],
         backgroundColor: [
            '#4db6ac',
            '#eceff1',
         ],
         borderColor: [
            '#FFF',
            '#FFF'
         ],
         borderWidth: 2
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      cutoutPercentage: 50,
      animation: {
         animateRotate: true
      },
      legend: {
         display: true,
         position: 'bottom',
         labels: {
            generateLabels: function() {
               return [{
                  text: 'CPU',
                  fillStyle: '#42a5f5',
                  strokeStyle: '#fff'
               }, {
                  text: 'MEM',
                  fillStyle: '#4db6ac',
                  strokeStyle: '#fff'
               }];
            }
         }
      },
      elements: {
         center: {
            text: 'CPU/MEM',
            fontStyle: 'Helvetica', //Default Arial
            sidePadding: 50 //Default 20 (as a percentage)
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="responseChartCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks alot! One more question is there anyway to add padding on the centering of the legend? With 2 keys it looks like it needs to move to the right just a bit as seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/JB4rvCS.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, NO !!